# Device permission for microphone

Tags: phonegap

I have an app which requires speech recognition.
When I test my app with chrome browser, it works just fine. (ask for permission and when allowed, we can record)

But When I sign my apk with phonegap build and test the apk on a device, it is not working. I think I need device permission for using microphone. But I don't know how to add code to ask for microphone permission.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Android :**

> Step 1 : Go to app -> src -> main -> AndroidManifest.xml.
>    Step 2 :Add Permision.
>
> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> ```

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.snazzyapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<!-- other permissions go here -->

<application ...>
    ...
</application>
```

For More Details CHECK [This:](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) And [This](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous)

**iOS:**

> **Step 1 :** Go to `info.plist`
>   **Step 1 :** Add Permision.

[image]

[image]